# Cassandra conditional update to collection

Tags: collections, cassandra, cql, cqlsh

I have a table that has is a simple key-value store, where the key is uuid, and value is a map of UDT(user defined type).

Example row as JSON:

```
{
  "id" = "123-123-12321",
  "map" = {
    "object1": {
      "value": "1",
      "timestamp": "2016-11-22 09:37:39.197000+0000"
    },
    "object2": {
      "value": "2",
      "timestamp": "2016-11-22 09:37:39.197000+0000"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to perform a update to one of the object in the map only if the given update object has a later timestamp, e.g.:

```
"object2": {
      "value": "3",
      "timestamp": "2011-10-11 23:13:42.321000+0000"
}
```

would override the the "object2" key in the map, because it carries a later timestamp.

How to write such update?

Comment: You need to do it in the application layer.

Answer (score 0):

> Every write (insert/update/delete) to cassandra, a timestamp associated with each column is also inserted. when you execute read query, timestamps are used to pick a "winning" update within a single column or collection element

Cassandra allow user to explicitly set that timestamp along with insert/update/delete statement with `USING TIMESTAMP epoch_in_microseconds` that will be used to pick the "winning" update.

**So how can we use this ?**

Every time you insert/update convert your timestamp value to `epoch_in_microseconds` and use it with `USING TIMESTAMP converted_value`.

Example :

```
INSERT INTO data(id, map) VALUES('123-123-12321', {'object2' : {value : '2', timestamp : '2017-09-09 16:24:06.197000+0000'}}) USING TIMESTAMP 1504952646912000;
```

Here `1504952646912000` is the converted value from `2017-09-09 16:24:06.197000+0000`

And

```
UPDATE data SET map['object2'] = {value : '3', timestamp : '2017-09-09 16:08:42.197000+0000'} WHERE id = '123-123-12321' USING TIMESTAMP 1504951722676000;
```

Finally your output will be value 2 of the key `object2`